# How to set build order in Qt subdir project

Tags: qt, build, build-process, qmake

I have a project with 5-6 libraries and one executable. The executable depends on the libraries, and some libraries depend on other libraries. How can I specify a build order so the dependencies are built before they are needed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok. I found the solution.Just add ordered to CONFIG and recite subdirs in correct order

```
CONFIG += ordered

SUBDIRS += Utility GraphicModule PackingLib Core GameProto
```

For me this work fine

Comment: The 'CONFIG += ordered' can have a devastating effect on multicore compile times. Please consider strict definition of dependencies as in my answer below.

Comment: @BogdanWilli No, it will not, unless you have a terribly slow single-threaded linker; aside from that, use `jom` on Windows and `make -jN` (with N==Ncores/threads) on *NIX; funny thing is, even if linking (which *is* single-threaded usually) takes lots of time, it means, there are lots of object files to link, compiling which obviously has had much longer time (== build times are hardly dominated by linking); 

another thing with ordered configs is greater reprodiciblity of builds (and easier error handling, despite things being parallel for each project)

Comment: @mlvljr, Link time is always an issue. See the efforts by clang and gcc to reduce that time.
Qmake has been updated and behaves different than 4 years ago. But the situation is still far from good. Instead of fixing qmake, the developers have created a new tool called QBS (which has it's own problems). There is a comment in their bugtracker saying that they will not fix qmake build-order issues because it is too difficult in the presence of the "ordered" argument.

Comment: @BogdanWilli may be, to each their own, though, you just have to be able to cook it right with the tools of your choice (mine is ordered builds); worst case is relying on internet advice, while not knowing the rationale behind it :)

Answer (score 34):

**Update:** (Feb 2021)

- Oct 2018 - [Qt decided to deprecate Qbs](https://www.qt.io/blog/2018/10/29/deprecation-of-qbs) and redirect its resources to increase support for CMake.
- Oct 2020 - [CMake is the build system for Qt 6](https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-6-build-system).

Please consume the advice in the (old) answer below in light of this new information.

---

Although this question has been answered and accepted a long time ago, I feel the need to add another answer; I honestly think that there is a better answer.

I consider `CONFIG += ordered` harmful and a bad habit. It is probably something that was a bit prematurely introduced by the qmake developers. And there are [strong opponents](http://blog.rburchell.com/2013/10/every-time-you-configordered-kitten-dies.html) to its use. The drawbacks are these:

1. it does **not** define the dependencies, it just names a build order
2. it hammers multicore build times
3. it prevents Qt developers from [implementing meaningful features](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-8349)

Therefore, I suggest to change your project file as follows:

```make
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += Utility GraphicModule PackingLib Core GameProto

GameProto.depends = Core
Core.depends = PackingLib
PackingLib.depends = GraphicModule
GraphicModule.depends = Utility
```

This way the dependencies are clearly defined. You can also think of other, more complicated dependency hierarchies which are possible this way and absolutely impossible with the build order.

Unfortunately, `qmake` is not the best tool when it comes to larger projects with deep sub-project hierarchies. Problems seen with larger projects are these:

- it is not possible to define dependencies to sub-projects higher up in the hierarchy
- `Run qmake` takes an extremely long time to execute
- long compile time because the dependencies are not handled properly and too many unnecessary compile steps executed
- sometimes `qmake` is not able to correctly calculate sub-project dependencies which makes it necessary to compile sub-projects separately

There mainly two ways to address these issues:

- Rewrite your project to a flat hierarchy. All executables, static and dynamic libraries should be in the topmost level. Use two or more levels only for sub-projects where you absolutely cannot avoid it. (e.g. a dynamic library that comprises of static libraries) This will result in shorter `qmake` run times and shorter compilation times. However, even this approach may fail at times.
- Change to a different make tool, like `cmake`. Seriously. `Cmake` is a mature product and the support from within Qt Creator is comparable to `qmake`.

Because of the well known problems with `qmake`, the Qt Company has already decided to introduce a new make tool `QBS`. However, the use of this tool is not as simple as it may look on first impression. There is no easy transition from `qmake` to `QBS`, especially for more complex projects. The Javascript-like syntax of the `QBS` language is not easy to grasp and documentation is scarce.

There are IMHO only two other tools available that are of the caliber to replace `qmake`:

- [`CMake`](https://cmake.org/), the well known build tool.
- [`meson`](http://mesonbuild.com/), an open source build system meant to be both extremely fast, and, even more importantly, as user friendly as possible.

Comment: This is not only better in terms of performance but also in terms of readability. Definitely the right answer for the question at hand.